# Serving user from different servers

Tags: java, session, tomcat, mean-stack

I am building a catalogue web application (online shopping like amazon, ebay) and I am using the MEAN stack to serve the data. I have all the product information stored in the mongo.

What I want to do is that, when a user wants to buy a product i.e. he clicks on the buy button, he should be redirected to another server (running MySQL and tomcat) for the rest of the procedure. In other words, I want to handle the user orders on the java and mySQL side. I also want to authenticate the user at this point of time i.e. manage sessions.

In this scenario, obviously I can not share session info across the two servers. So, my question is that how do I provide transparency to the user? I don't want the user to know that he is being served by a different server when placing an order.

The primary aim here is to let the user browse the catalogue freely and place order, without letting him know that he is being served by two servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize the session on the MEAN server, send it over to Tomcat, have it deserialized there and parsed into an active session object. Then, you could do a redirect with the session ID as a query parameter (Cookies won't work as they are limited to be read from the original server) and connect the incoming user to the session object created earlier. You have to find a way to circumvent all countermeasures which are there to prevent session hijacking, though.

The question is: why would you want to do so? This architecture breaks at least two basic principles([DRY](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) [KISS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)). This system will be harder to maintain (both development and operations wise), more prone to downtime (there are - at least - four parts which can fail instead of one *and* you have to leverage security measures on the Tomcat side to make it work the first place.

Assuming that you have the tomcat side ready (by yourself or provided): simply set it's context path to something like `/shop` and put the rest of your app to `/` on the tomcat server. Removes a level of complexity, should be easier to maintain and deploy.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am building this just to get hand on some of the technologies and to understand how they can communicate with each other.